# How to keep ui-router parameters on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using a `ui-sref` which takes two strings and an object as parameters.  All works fine under normal circumstances, however when I refresh the browser on the page which I have navigated to the object becomes null.

The two strings in the URL are fine after a refresh.  Is there a way to get the object to persist in the `$stateparams` after a page refresh.  I have tried several options such as `$rootscope.$stateparams = $stateparams`, I've tried using a service too but it gets wiped on a refresh.  Using local storage is not an option.

```
.state('edit', {
        url: '/editItem/:id?userId',
        templateUrl: 'app/items/edit.html',
        controller: 'editController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        params: { 
            id: "",
            userId: "",
            userObject: null,
        }
})
```

I really just need the object to persist on reload.  I'm using UI-router 1.0.0-beta.2

Comment: Why are you setting object as null if you dont want it to be null?

Comment: What is `object`? It looks like you're just setting it to `null` everytime

Comment: @GustavoGabriel That is how you define parameters on the state definition.

Comment: I think you are going to end up having to either re-create the object or save it (cookies are an alternative to local storage). When the user refreshes the browser is going to reload all the javascript so everything is going to be back in its initial state. There is no magic parameter that will automatically reload and set the state back to what it was prior to the refresh - you have to do that.

Comment: @DustinToothless I'm just setting the params to null in the state definition then I pass in the correct values using a ui-sref({id:id, userId: userId, object: nonNullObject})

Comment: @Lex I was hoping I could avoid recreating the user object as I have already got those details I wanted to avoid having to do a second get request on the new page.  The url parameters persist ok I thought maybe there was some solution to get non url params to do the same

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate, but such is the nature of a stateless framework.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your url params in your state everytime, you can use the `resolve` function:

```
.state('edit', {
        url: '/editItem/:id/:userId',
        templateUrl: 'app/items/edit.html',
        controller: 'editController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          testObject: function($stateParams) {
             return {
              id: $stateParams.id,
              userId: $stateParams.userId
             }
          }
        }

    })
```

Now, you can pass `testObject` as a dependency to your `editController` and every time this route is resolved, the values will be available within your controller as `testObject.id` and `testObject.userId`

If you want to pass an object from one state to the next, use `$state.go` programatically:

```
$state.go('myState', {myParam: {some: 'thing'}})

$stateProvider.state('myState', {
                url: '/myState',
                params: {myParam: null}, ...
```

The only other option is to cache, trough Localstorage or cookies

Comment: I don't see how this solves the issue.  In the original question I have stated the two url strings are ok i.e. they persist even with a page refresh.  My issue is I have a non url object (now called userObject) which I want to pass from one state to another using a ui-sref.  This works.  However a page refresh wipes the userObject but not the two url strings (id and userId).  My question is how to persist the userObject on page refresh.

Comment: That was not clear in the original question. Thanks for clarifying. I have updated my answer.